# How to replace a text in a complete Google Spreadsheet

Tags: replace, spreadsheet

I try to make a script which replace a value (e.g. 1 to x). This is my script:

```
function myOwnReplaceTest(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = ss.getName();

  for (var r = 1; r <= ss.getLastRow(); ++r) {
    for (var c = 1; c <= ss.getLastColumn(); ++c) {
    var sr = ss.getRange(r, c).getValue();
    var re = sr.toString().replace(1,'x');
    ss.getRange(r, c).setValue(re);
    }
  }
}
```

It works fine, but very very slow in a bigger list (eg. 1000 lines and 10 columns).

When i test the same function about "STRG+H" it works in 5 Seconds.

Does anyone have a tip for me how I can make my script faster?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices where it describes "use batch operations"

Comment: Hello, i´m to stupid for this example or the week was to long. It is outrageous when i ask you for a example for my example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the article on which I commented, the following should be faster because it writes only once. I had to rewrite the loops to get my indices to match up nicely.

```
function myOwnReplaceTest(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = ss.getName();
  var newVals = new Array(ss.getLastRow());


  for (var r = 0; r < ss.getLastRow(); r++) {
    newVals[r]=new Array(ss.getLastColumn()-1);
    for (var c = 0; c < ss.getLastColumn(); c++) {
    var sr = ss.getRange(r+1, c+1).getValue();
    var re = sr.toString().replace(1,'x');
      newVals[r][c]=re;
    //ss.getRange(r, c).setValue(re);
    }
  }
  //Browser.msgBox(newVals);
  ss.getRange(1,1,newVals.length,newVals[0].length).setValues(newVals);
}
```

Presumably it can be further souped up by reading the data into an array, too.
Edit: Here is what that looks like.

```
function myOwnReplaceTest(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = ss.getName();
  var newVals = new Array(ss.getLastRow());
  var allSr = ss.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow(),ss.getLastColumn());
  //Browser.msgBox(allSr.getValues());


  for (var r = 0; r < ss.getLastRow(); r++) {
    newVals[r]=new Array(ss.getLastColumn()-1);
    for (var c = 0; c < ss.getLastColumn(); c++) {
    //var sr = ss.getRange(r+1, c+1).getValue();
      var sr = allSr.getCell(r+1, c+1).getValue();
    var re = sr.toString().replace(1,'x');
      newVals[r][c]=re;
    //ss.getRange(r, c).setValue(re);
    }
  }
  //Browser.msgBox(newVals);
  ss.getRange(1,1,newVals.length,newVals[0].length).setValues(newVals);
}
```

I would hope that will speed it up a little further. The other tweak might be to not call getLastColumn() so many times, but I imagine that is not a big factor. The key here is that all the operations in the inner for loop are now in memory.