# setValues from JSON array to spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, setvalue

I'm stuck trying to copy the values from my JSON scraping script to spreadsheet.

Does anyone know how to do that?

I'm stuck trying to know how to get the "longname" values to the memory and then using setValue once at the end.

I need to paste all the values [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFjXz.png) at the column B.

First I'm trying to resolve a single column, later I will need to paste a multi dimensional array to multiple columns. But that's only if I solve this.

Just a detail, on columnWithTickers I used only a range of 5 rows for testing purposes. Later I will use a dynamic value.

Code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var page1 = ss.getSheetByName("pag1");
let columnWithTickers = page1.getRange(2, 1, 5).getValues();
let targetColumn = page1.getRange(2, 2);


function printValuesFromJSON() {
  if (!Array.isArray(columnWithTickers)) {
    columnWithTickers = [[columnWithTickers]]
  }

  return columnWithTickers.map(tickers => {
    try {

      values = tickers[0].toString().split(",");
      let url = `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/${values}.SA/key-statistics?p=${values}.SA`;
      let source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
      let jsonString = source.match(/root.App.main = ([\s\S\w]+?);\n/)
      if (!jsonString || jsonString.length == 1) return;
      let data = JSON.parse(jsonString[1].trim());
      let longname = data.context.dispatcher.stores.QuoteSummaryStore.price.longName.split();

      /*let resultados = longname.map(vetor =>{
        return ativosResultados = vetor[0].toString();     
      })*/

    }
    catch (error) {
      return "N/A"
    }
  }

  )

}
```

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but setValues wants an array parameter, so pass it  something like [longname], not longname.

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried that and some other approaches...none of them worked

Comment: getRange(2,2,1) or equivalently getRange(2,2) should help. You are getting 5 rows now, and I think that's causing your trouble. Eventually, don't hard code passing row 2 or you'll overwrite your previous entry. Use a function to get the last or max row, then go beyond it.

Comment: I've managed by adding the getlastrow function...but I'm finding very slow. The function exceeded the 6 minutes time limit at the 365th value

Comment: I thought that by using setValue for each loop would be the solution...but I can see that's not going to be sustainable...my final script will have to deal with almost 1000 row and almost 30 columns. I have to manage to pass the values from each loop to an Array and then pass the Array to setValue...the problem is, I don't know how to achieve that

Comment: It's impossible to fix and test without knowing what ` SpreadsheetApp` is and how it does whatever it does and what it takes as input if at all, what exactly those methods can do and how do they do whatever they do. Does it have other methods that were not included in the OP code? Also, are there English equivalent names for some of those variables?

Comment: The performance will get better if you maintain the values in in memory arrays and use getValues to read once at the begiining and setValues once at the end after you're done filling the array. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409394/how-to-replace-a-text-in-a-complete-google-spreadsheet/45636190#45636190

Comment: @JeremyKahan Thanks for the example! That's pretty much what I'm trying to do. To use setValues() only once at the end. The problem is that if I call setValues after the function, it becomes unrecheable. Even with the example, I'm still stuck with that because I'm not being able to adapt to my script.

Comment: @zer00ne Hey, I updated the code with english words. See if that helps

Comment: After `columnWithTickers` add this `console.log(columnWithTickers)`. What does `columnWithTickers` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below function:

```
function attDiarios(){
  var result = intervaloTickers.map(tickersAtuais => 
    {      
      ativosFinais = tickersAtuais[0].toString().split(" ")

      let url = `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/${ativosFinais}.SA/key-statistics?p=${ativosFinais}.SA`;
      let source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
      let jsonString = source.match(/root.App.main = ([\s\S\w]+?);\n/)
      if (!jsonString || jsonString.length == 1) return null;
      let data = JSON.parse(jsonString[1].trim());    
      try{
        var longNameValue = data.context.dispatcher.stores.QuoteSummaryStore.price.longName;
        }
      catch(err){
        var longNameValue = 'N/A';
      }
      return [[longNameValue]]
    }
  )
  sImport.getRange(5, 2, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
}
```